# remove linux-image-generic after installing linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04?

Tags: kernel, hardware-enablement-stack

is it safe to remove linux-image-generic after installing linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04?

if you don't care about reverting back that is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as long as the `linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04` is working you can remove the old kernels.

See [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the `--dry-run` options to `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg --dry-run --remove linux-image-generic
```